# Grafana with cloudwatch at lightsail is possible?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, grafana, amazon-lightsail

I have an instance on amazon lightsail and I setup grafana with cloudwatch datasource. When I list the regions, I see a few options but i don't see us-east-b (Ohio) where my instance is running.

Does cloudwatch only work with EC2?

Anybody got to use grafana and cloudwatch with a Lightsail instance?

Answer (score 1):

Lightsail does not send it's monitoring data to CloudWatch; at least not in a way that can be accessed by an end customer. You would need to implement a monitoring solution on the LightSail instance and push the logs to S3 or similar storage for Graphana to read from.

**Addition**: After some attempts it would appear the installable CloudWatch Agent will not work with Lightsail. Selecting `onPremise` or `EC2` during the configuration of the CloudWatch Agent results in different errors when running the agent.